# Kiosk view of remote machine X11vnc

Tags: vnc

I need to connect to a remote machine through vnc viewer applet embedded in a webpage.
The remote machine will host a program running on the desktop connected through the viewer.

I need to enable the viewers to view only the running application program without access to any other feature such as the desktop and/or the task bar.

How can I achieve this?

BTW, I am experimenting with x11vnc -id, -sid command options, but got no desired view.

Please help as I am in a bit urgency.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Try superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

In the X initialization commands, only run the WM and application, not a full desktop environment.

```
metacity &
exec someapp
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I would appreciate if you could be more explanatory on the solution.
I am not getting how to initiate a WM for a vnc server for an application.

Comment: Well, how do you currently start the DE?

Comment: I guess DE stands for "desktop environment" ?
basically we have the x11vnc running with root user...

Comment: That's correct. GNOME, KDE, etc.

Comment: so you need me to add the suggested command text in line to the xterm line in the DE startup script?

or you can suggest me one

Comment: FYI,
I have attempted with the following command:
 x11vnc -storepasswd .vnc/passwd -ssl SAVE -http -display :1 -auth /var/gdm/:0.Xauth -sid 0x2a0000c

Comment: Get rid of the DE startup script entirely and use the commands listed above.

Comment: it worked !!

thanks for your help..
just few cleanups at my end..
thanks you very much